# Script to generate CSS properties with random colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a bunch (800) CSS properties each with a different color in this format:

```
#mydiv[terr="T368"] {
  polygon-fill: #F11810;
}
```

I found this handy script to generate random HEX colors (http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/):

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

I'm a bit new to javascript and can't put together a loop that does the following:

The number next to the "T" needs to be incremented from 1 to 800 with each `TXXX` having a unique color. It's fine if there are duplicates of colors throughout the 800, I can go back and fix that by hand. No need to add a function that ensures there are duplicates.

What I'm looking for is a script that generates 800 css properties like this:

```
#mydiv[terr="T100"] {
  polygon-fill: #F11810;
}
#mydiv[terr="T101"] {
  polygon-fill: #e2e2e2;
}
#mydiv[terr="T102"] {
  polygon-fill: #6A3D9A;
}
...etc, etc.
```

Yes, the `#mydiv` remains the same. This is specific CSS for CartoDB, so the formatting is specific to that.

I just need the 800 CSS properties to generate so I can copy and paste them into CartoDB.

PS: Bonus points for handling the case of all Ts before 100, which are formatted like this, for example: T001 and T050.

EDIT: Got very close on my own, but could use help on my "bonus" question above. H

```
for (rep = 1; rep <= 800; rep++) {
  var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);  
    document.write('#mydiv[territory="T' + rep + '"] {<br> polygon-fill:#'   +color+';<br>}<br>');
}
```

Comment: How would you give "bonus points"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple script that will generate the stuff you want. You can copy the formatted css from the textarea.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/4zda86ta/1/)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var output = $("#output");
for (var i = 0; i < 801; i++) {
    var color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    var css = "#mydiv[terr='T" + i + "']{\n polygon-fill: " + color + ";\n}\n";
    output.append(css);
}
```

Comment: This works, and completely answers the question.  Fair warning to the OP, though, using the *full* numeric range of hex colors might not work well across all browsers, and may result in colors that aren't useful for your use case (too dark, too light, not enough contrast with surrounding colors, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it all (including my bonus question). Of note, occasionally, this random color generator creates a HEX with 5 characters that's invalid, but I can't quite figure out why, so I had to go through each one by hand to find them, but not a big issue for my challenge.

```
for (rep = 1; rep <= 800; rep++) {
  var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  if (rep < 10)  {
    document.write('#mydiv[territory="T00' + rep + '"] {<br> polygon-fill:#' +color+';<br>}<br>');
  }
  if (rep >=10 && rep <100)
  {
    document.write('#mydiv[territory="T0' + rep + '"] {<br> polygon-fill:#' +color+';<br>}<br>');
}
if (rep >= 100)  {
    document.write('#mydiv[territory="T' + rep + '"] {<br> polygon-fill:#' +color+';<br>}<br>');
}
}
```

Comment: To avoid 5 letter colours you can use for colour: ('00000'+Math.random().toString(16).replace('.', '')).slice(-6) and for on line 4 similarily ('00' + rep).slice(-3)

Comment: PS Instead "for on line 4" read "for rep on line 4" and you dont need if's after that.

Comment: @RauliRajande Not quite following what you're suggesting here.

Comment: To avoid shorter strings, add zeros to the beginning of the string/number and then cut last n characters from it. This way you don't have to put three ifs there just to check "rep" length and no worries about 5 letter colour codes.